# How to get data from DB to fill specific fields in a form when an option from a dropdown menu is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, typeahead.js

I'm making an app in **Laravel 5.7**.

I want to have a form to upload house properties, so there's an input that should get data from the DB while typing (using **Typeahead.js**).

So, when a user clicks an option of the dropdown menu, let's say the *ZipCode*, the *Address* and *State* *should be automatically filled with the data associated with that clicked ZipCode*.

I don't really have a code trying to do that since I don't know how to, but any guidiance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your server side you can do something like this.

```
$address = Address::where('address', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')->limit(10)->get();

return response()->json($address, $this->status, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

In your js file use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for your http request and based on the response you can retrieve the related data like address, zipcode and more..